# How to Tell if Browser Can Display a Unicode Character

Tags: javascript, unicode, fonts, browser

Is there a way using javascript to tell if a browser is capable of displaying a unicode character?

For example, my brower can display ⬆ (&#11014;) but it can not display ⬀ (&#11008;)